# Compare 2 input files and reorder

Tags: string, file-io, awk

I am new to awk.

I have 2 input files called file1 and file2.

Each record of file1 has the literal form: X where X is some string.

Each record of file2 has the literal form: abY where Y is also some string and ab is a variable two-letter-prefix.

The number of records in file 1 is the same as that of file 2.

The collection of Y's is just a re-ordering of the collection of X's.

I would like a one-liner to compare each line of file1 (of the form X) with each line of file2 (of the form abY) such that when X is a match for Y in abY, print abY to an output file called file3.

I have been really struggling with this for a few days now. I have tried modifying many one-liners based on similar stack questions involving awk string comparison of two input files, but with no desired results.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a line that does the job.  I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this...

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {for (i in a) if (substr(i,3)==$0) {print i}}' file2 file1 > file3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
awk 'FNR<NR {if(substr($0,3) in buf) print $0; next;} {buf[$0]=0}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, @SomeGuy.  Your code outputs the contents of file2 (i.e. it prints the string format abY in the order in which it is found in file2) - This is as far as I had got too before struggling.What I am trying to do is to output the string format abY according to the order in which Y (the match for X of file1) appears in file1.